# PostGIS geography returns area < 0.0

Tags: postgis, postgresql, antimeridian

I am trying to convert a geometry column to a geography column and calculate the area using this query:

```
SELECT dccode,SUM(CAST(St_Area(geom::geography,true) AS NUMERIC)) as Area 
       FROM  schema.table   
       GROUP BY dccode
```

but I am getting a strange error:

```
...
NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY
NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY
NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY
NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY
NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY


ERROR:  lwgeom_area_spher(oid) returned area < 0.0
********** Error **********

ERROR: lwgeom_area_spher(oid) returned area < 0.0
```

I've run this query to verify that there is no invalid geometry:

```
select gid, dccode, st_isvalidreason(geom) from table.schema where st_isvalid(geom) = false;
```

but it doesn't return anything. How can I isolate the geometry that is < 0.0?

Comment: what srid is your geometry data in? the coercing to rang warning is probably the issue

Comment: It is in srid 4326

Comment: and is it lon/lat or lat/lon?

Comment: not sure I follow? it's a multipolygon geom field...

Comment: but which way are the coordinates stored? it seems PostGIS believes some of your coordinates lay off planet and it is moving them to make a Geography polygon.

Comment: looking at st_astext(geom), it is returning lon, lat

Comment: The other error which will generate negative area is incorrect polygon ring rotation. Please [Edit] the question to provide an example of your coordinates.

Comment: You can get the area of each feature by dropping the SUM `SELECT dccode,CAST(St_Area(geom::geography,true) AS NUMERIC) as Area`.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue with geometries that spanned the antimeridian, but which were brought into PostGIS with SRS 4326. Casting to the `Geography` type seemed to introduce some issue with vertex ordering, although I'm not sure about the exact nature of this issue. Projecting to an appropriate antimeridian-spanning CRS for my region of interest before calculating the area addressed the issue. So: `ST_Area(ST_Transform(geom, 3851))`, using https://epsg.io/3851